# How to change Querystring value in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Can someone please help me how to change the querystring value in URL?

Here is example of links

**Example:1**
[https://www.flipkart.com/footwear/paragon~brand/pr?affid=RANDOMVALUE&sort=price_asc&sid=osp](https://www.flipkart.com/footwear/paragon%7Ebrand/pr?affid=RANDOMVALUE&sort=price_asc&sid=osp)

**Example:2**
https://www.flipkart.com/mens-footwear/pr?marketplace=FLIPKART&rwua=175f4d7321d&cpvp=1606130545181&nozq=25d72e9a2dc7&sort=price_asc&sid=osp%2Ccil&rvop=1606130052551&ysl=&p%5B%5D=facets.discount_range_v1%255B%255D%3D70%2525%2Bor%2Bmore&p%5B%5D=facets.fulfilled_by%255B%255D%3DFlipkart%2BAssured&p%5B%5D=facets.brand%255B%255D%3DLotto&p%5B%5D=facets.availability%255B%255D%3DInclude%2BOut%2Bof%2BStock&ozc=tda&affid=RANDOMVALUE

I want to change the querystring **affid=** value, this Querystring either start with **?affid=RANDOMVALUE** or **&affid=RANDOMVALUE**

This querystring has any random value. I want to replace it with my value.

I have tried to use [furl](https://pypi.org/project/furl/)

here is code which I tried

```
 LIST_OF_QUERY_PARAMETERS_TO_REMOVE = ['tag', 'affid','affExtParam1','affExtParam2']
 result = furl.furl(full_url)
 final_url = result.remove(LIST_OF_QUERY_PARAMETERS_TO_REMOVE).url
```

by above code, I am getting following result.

> 'https://www.flipkart.com/footwear/paragon~brand/pr?sort=price_asc&sid=osp'

is there any better way yo replace just value of specific querystring in URL?

Comment: Why some one down vote of this question? what is wrong in this?

Comment: You want to replace `affid=AnyValue` with `affid=MyValue`, and leave the rest of the URL unchanged?

Comment: @MartinKleiven yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `affid` doesn't show up anywhere else in the string but where you want it to, you can simply use regexes. No need to actually manipulate the URL and in any complicated matter. Simply substitute by the `[&?]affid=` pattern found in the strings.

```py
import re


def replacer(match):
    prefix = match.group(1)
    infix = "MyValue"
    suffix = match.group(3)

    # could also use f-strings: f'{prefix}{infix}{suffix}'
    # if you are on Python >= 3.6
    result = '{}{}{}'.format(prefix, infix, suffix)
    return result

def replace_affid(url, suffix):
    pattern = r'(.*[?&]affid=)(\w+)(&.*)'
    return re.sub(pattern, replacer, url)



a = "https://www.flipkart.com/footwear/paragon~brand/pr?affid=RANDOMVALUE"
b = "https://www.flipkart.com/mens-footwear/pr?marketplace=FLIPKART&affid=RANDOMVALUE"
print(replace_affid(a, "MyValue"))
print(replace_affid(b, "MyValue"))
```

Comment: ohhh how stupid I am !! why I didn't think about regular expression. Thank you !!